# Life, the Universe, and Everything spoj compilation error in java

Tags: java

*Question:
Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely... rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits.*

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Life 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
        int count;
        for(count=0;count>=0;count++)
        {
            int num=input.nextInt();
            if(num==42)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                out.println(num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gives the same output after compilation but saying compilation error in SPOJ can anyone tell what's wrong with that. thanks.

Comment: What is SPOJ?  And what is the error message?

Comment: spoj.com is an onine judge system .google for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should avoid using Public class.`class Life` will work

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;
class Life 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
        int count;
        for(count=0;count>=0;count++)
        {
            int num=input.nextInt();
            if(num==42)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                out.println(num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program compiles and runs well, but don't call your class `Life`, it is required that you use a class named `Main`.

There is just a single mistake, your for loop is wrong as your control variable may overflow which will cause the end of the loop even if you don't input "42". Use a *never ending" loop as :

```
while (true) {
  …
}
```

or

```
for (;;) {
  …
}
```